# Не получается распаковать сжатый пакет minecraft

Tags: python, minecraft, zlib

Я пытаюсь распаковывать пакеты, которые сервер передает клиенту. Согласно [документации](https://wiki.vg/Protocol#With_compression) они сжимаются при помощи `zlib`. Поэтому в своем коде на питоне, я использую функцию `zlib.decompress`, но получаю вот такую ошибку:

```
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check
```

Вот код, который отвечает за парсинг пакетов:

```
compression =  False

def parse_packet(data):
    global compression
    cursor = 0
    print("Compression: ", compression)
    print("packet_len:", VarInt.decode(data))
    cursor += getNumLen(data)
    if compression:
        decompressed_packet_len = VarInt.decode(data[cursor:])
        print("decompressed_packet_len:", decompressed_packet_len)
        cursor += getNumLen(data[cursor:])
        if decompressed_packet_len != 0:
            data = zlib.decompress(data[cursor:])
        print("packet_id: ", hex(VarInt.decode(data[cursor:])))
        cursor += getNumLen(data[cursor:])
    else:
        print("packet_id: ", hex(VarInt.decode(data[cursor:])))
        if VarInt.decode(data[cursor:]) == 3:
            compression = True
        cursor += getNumLen(data[cursor:])
    print("\n")
```

Comment: Я ничего не знаю про протокол minecraft, но от балды можно предположить, что он не использует zlib-заголовок — попробуйте сделать `zlib.decompress(b"\x78\x9c" + data[cursor:])`

Comment: @andreymal, попробовал сделать то, что вы сказали, теперь получаю ошибку `zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid stored block lengths`